# finding the limit of a sequence including sigma symbol

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I have a sequence  : $$\sum_{k=1}^n e^{\frac{k}{n^2}}\times \ln(k+\frac{1}{k})$$
I have to find the limit of this sequence , I tried to surround it ,but this not the correct way.

Comment: This is a series.

Comment: @KushalBhuyan - If $n$ didn't appear in the element expression, then it would be a series. But since the element expression does depend on $n$, it is not a series.

Comment: @Colbi - there is no other meaning for the limit of a sequence than as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that all the terms are positive, then consider just the behavior of the term $k = n$.